# what is the right way to update List view inside widget after changes made in config file

Tags: android, service, android-listview, widget, android-remoteview

i would like to know how to refresh listview inside widget .

on my config file i use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

after you edit the config file .

maybe i can refresh the all widget somehow ?

i guess what i am asking is :

what is the right way to update list after changes made in config file .

note that if i remove the widget and add it again it shows the widget with the new config .

thanks for advance for explaining this issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance of the adapter of the listview and call the notifyDataSetChanged() of the adapter instance.

Comment: the Adapter cant be notifyDataSetChanged() , my adapter is implements RemoteViewsFactory .